# Where did the help pages go?

Tags: support, help-pages

So there is a new top banner bar on my SE pages today, and I can't figure out where the help pages went (links to the Tour, Help Center, etc.). What am I missing?

[image: Current EL&U top banner, showing in top bar, left to right: StackExchange link; Search box; my icon and current score; badges; message icon; awards icon; search queue icon; icon for all other SEs.]

Comment: It appears the number of  review queues is no longer available.

Comment: Nope, and if you look at any of them the red alert goes away, even if you don't clear any queues. Presumably until you go away and come back, or something.

Comment: @Josh: You can see the numbers if you go to the "all queues" page: https://english.stackexchange.com/review But it is not displayed on the main page any more

Comment: The new top banner is a good example of fixing something that wasn't broken and a "good idea" that wasn't.  Two thumbs down!

Comment: @Josh The numbers in the previous menu bar didn't match the numbers reported in-queue, but at least it gave an indication of how long the queues were. The new menu bar will take some getting used to, to say the least.

Comment: Something's wrong with the link or my browser. Clicking on it reports `The image "https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVtg8.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.` Laurel's links (only visible when trying to edit the answer) also produce similar error messages.

Comment: @Lawrence - I think that the number that appeared on the front page was a way to call for "intervention" from user to reduce the queues. Now, how long the queues are, is much less evident.

Comment: @Josh Yes, it's a lot less informative now. If they wanted less clutter, perhaps a happy medium would be a coloured icon, with colours going from blue or green for short queues to red for long queues.

Comment: @Lawrence By link do you mean the image of the banner? Can you see the picture at all? I'm not seeing the error message on my desktop or phone; what browser are you using?

Comment: @1006a I was using firefox. Now running Chrome, it displays without problem. Possibly a problem with my browser.

Comment: *sigh* the old banner. No news from the community manager, and no new ideas/fixes have been presented since… "boh" (Italian expression)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's one link in the site switcher dropdown:

[image: help, chat, log out]

And one under the ? menu (now shown to all users):

[image]

And one in the footer:

[image]

And here’s the link (since the app doesn’t have a direct way to get there):

https://english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did actually look in the footer, but missed it. It did not occur to me to look in the "list of all 171 Stack Exchange sites" (that's the hover text).